# Recursive function that takes an array and displays the elements in reverse order

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

I just want to print the array in reverse order using a recursive function.
Below is my code. This code prints all the characters in reverse but the very first element is always missing since the last return is always array(1)(1 being the index of array..... I don't actually know the memory address) and not array(0).

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void array(char *s){
    if(*s=='\0') return;
    array(++s);
    printf("%c",*s);
}
int main(){
    char s[20];
    gets(s);
    cout<<"\n";
    array(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
 array(++s)
```

to

```
 array(s+1)
```

so you keep the proper value of `s` for the `printf` statement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

void array(char *s){
    if(*s=='\0') return;
    array(s+1);
    printf("%c",*s);
}
int main(){
    char s[20];
    gets(s);
    cout<<"\n";
    array(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the method:

```
void array(char *s){
    if(*s=='\0') return;
    array(++s);
    printf("%c",*s);
}
```

To:

```
void array(char *s){
    if(*s=='\0') return;
    array(s + sizeof(char));
    printf("%c",*s);
}
```

Because `++s` or `s++` changes the pointer variable which affects the `printf` and makes you always print the next character.

Comment: Yes, I had a typo and i fixed it, thanks for downvoting about it :)

Comment: Sizeof is not required, just use 1

Comment: It is wrong to put constants embedded in the code when you can avoid it, it makes your code less readable.

Comment: Actually I tried s++ first but no output was displayed. It goes out of scope without incrementing the value.

Comment: Yeah, in that case since `s++` first calls the function with s it will cause a stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this -

```
void array(char *s,int i)
{
    if(s[i]=='\0') return;
    array(s,i+1);          // i declared in main as int i=0 and call as array(s,i) in main
    printf("%c",s[i]);
 }
```

Comment: Global variables are a bad idea

Comment: @EdHeal  I removed it .

Answer (score 0):

your code was fine, but why aren't you getting answer is,
'\0' this works fine when the user types enter button ,to give another input but , while user was giving input he doesn't type enter at beginning, so your code doesn't work for that one letter.
now to manage this program you can do like this, store that first character in another variable and display it at last.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `array(s+1);` instead of `array(++s);` to preserve the first value.

N.B: It should be noted that you better use `sizeof()` when doing pointer arithmetic like that.

Comment: sizeof(T) will return the size of the type T. sizeof(float) returns 4 because that's how much memory is reserved for floats. sizeof(char) would return 1, which is what you typed in your program.